If $\nu \ll m$ and $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}; m)$, does it then follow necessarily that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}; \nu)$?
Let $m$ be a measure on the space $(X, \mathcal{F})$, $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}; m)$ and $\nu$ be a measure such that $\nu\ll m$. Does it then follow that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R};\nu)$? I have a feeling that this should not be true since the product of $L^1$ functions need not be in $L^1$; for example take $X = [0,1], \mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}([0,1]), f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $m$ the Lebesgue measure. However, the formula
$$\int_A fd\nu = \int_Af\cdot \frac{d\nu}{dm}dm$$
is valid when $\nu\ll m$ and $f$ is $\nu$ integrable and therefore I do not know whether simply taking $d\nu = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dm$ is sufficient to conclude this claim.

well, $x\mapsto 1/\sqrt x $ is $L^1(0,1)$. Do the same with $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ and you'll have your example.

@Surb I don't understand. To be specific, I don't know how I am supposed to integrate the candidate $f$ w.r.t. our $\nu$ to show that the integral blows up.

The formula $\int_A fd\nu = \int_Af\cdot \frac{d\nu}{dm}dm$ is valid for all non-negative measurable functions $f$.

Just let $\nu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, $m$ be the Gaussian measure. Then the constant function $1$ is integrable w.r.t. $m$ but not $\nu$.

You just need to find a function $f$ and a measures $\mu,\nu$ such that $\int f\,d\mu<\infty$ but $\int f\,\cdot\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\,d\mu=\infty$
There are many ways to do this. For example let $\mu$, $\nu$ be defined by $\mu(A)=\int_{A}e^{-x}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty]}\,dm$ and $\nu(A)=\int_{A}e^{\frac{x}{2}}\,d\mu$ for all $A\in\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.
i.e. $\nu(A)=\int_{A}e^{-x/2}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty]}\,dm$
Then $\nu<<\mu$ and $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=e^{x/2}$ .
Now let  $f(x)=e^{\frac{3x}{4}}$
Then $\int f\,d\mu=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}e^{\frac{3x}{4}}\,dm=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x/4}\,dm=4$
But $$\int f\,d\nu= \int e^{3x/4}\cdot e^{x/2}\,d\mu=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{3x/4}e^{x/2}e^{-x}\,dm=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{x/4}\,dm=\infty$$
Ofcourse there are even more simple examples as suggested in the comments.
For example if $\nu=m$ and $\mu(A)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{A}e^{-x^{2}/2}\,dm$.
Then it is easy to see that $\mu<<\nu$ and $\nu<<\mu$. But $\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{R}}\in L^{1}(\mu)$ but it is not $L^{1}(\nu)$.
The choice of $\frac{d\mu}{dm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^{2}/2}$ is a very special one as it is called the Normal or Gaussian probability density function. The constant $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is such that $\mu(\Bbb{R})=1$
